# google places API - restrict to return full addresses only

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Does anyone know a way to restrict Google Places API to return full address results only - ie those with the first two lines of an address.
I would like to cut out towns, and cities as they are too broad.

I see that postcodeanywhere provide full addresses only, however they don't have a free tier.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @paul did you figure out a way to restrict it?

Answer (score 0):

You have select which parameters you want to return from AUTOCOMPLETE ie `street_number` and `route` in your instance.

The basic usage is located here [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

Keep the following in mind; your input fields must be named per the Autocomplete parameters to work out of the box such as `street_number`, `route`, `postal_code` and so on or the API will not write to those fields inside your form.

Example JS from the fiddle I've included:

```
var placeSearch;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'long_name',
    route: 'long_name'
};

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.877461, -87.638085),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
mapOptions);

var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
(
document.getElementById('field_autocomplete'));

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(12); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div id="infowindow"><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    fillInAddress();
});

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
        });
    }
}
```

`var componentForm` is where you will specify which Autocomplete components you want to retrieve from the API.

Comment: What I was trying to do was see if only full addresses can be selected in the auto-complete (ie, imagine you need to select full address for a package delivery, there should be no option to just select "London"). I checked the jsfiddle and isolating elements after being selected isn't enough. I don't think Google allow this kind of address isolation, it's fine as there are other providers. Appreciate the effort and response all the same.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sad, I could really use an answer to this question and haven't found any other questions related to this subject.